# Count unique data within a category

Tags: mysql, sql, count, isql

I am looking for help in trying to solve an issue with a query.

Query:

```
SELECT distinct BRAND,(select count(distinct VIN) from STOCK) as STOCK ITEM COUNT
from STOCK
```

What I am trying to achieve is to display the brand and unique count of all VIN numbers which are located in each brand.

For some reason when I run the above query each brand eg, Ford,GM,TOYOTA, etc display the same count .

Comment: Students simply shouldn't learn the `distinct` keyword until they full understand `join`, `group by`, and `subqueries`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff talking about group by and subqueries is it possible to use a group by in a subquery, as I am having the same issue with another query I am doing where the calculated average amount is the same each row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or do a simple `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT BRAND, count(distinct VIN) as STOCK_ITEM COUNT
from STOCK
group by brand
```

Answer (score 2):

You're currently making a subquery that doesn't take `BRAND` into account. You want to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Brand, Count(*)
FROM Stock
GROUP BY Brand
```